# Why my HttpConfiguration type has no ServiceResolver type using .Net MVC 4 with WebApi?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I'm using .Net MVC 4 with WebApi and in all articles that explain how to use DI Container with that has the following line of configuration in Global.asax: (http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/03/20/RobustDIWithTheASPNETWebAPI.aspx)

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.ServiceResolver.SetResolver(...)
```

But in my application has not `ServiceResolver` type:

[image]

with intellisense:

[image]

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's been renamed to `DependencyResolver` in the RC:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = ... your custom DR
```

Comment: Reuse resolver, check this entry.
It’s The Little Things about ASP.NET MVC 4 http://haacked.com/archive/2012/03/11/itrsquos-the-little-things-about-asp-net-mvc-4.aspx